# Flask and mimerender exception handling

Tags: python, flask

I'm using the exception mapping from mimerender (let's take the json as example), however the output is different than when a request is working:

```
import json
import mimerender
...

mimerender = mimerender.FlaskMimeRender()

render_xml = lambda message: '<message>%s</message>'%message
render_json = lambda **args: json.dumps(args)
render_html = lambda message: '<html><body>%s</body></html>'%message
render_txt = lambda message: message

render_xml_exception = lambda exception: '<exception>%s</exception>'%exception
render_json_exception = lambda exception: json.dumps(exception.args)
render_html_exception = lambda exception: '<html><body>%s</body></html>'%exception
render_txt_exception = lambda exception: exception

@mimerender.map_exceptions(
    mapping=(
        (ValueError, '500 Internal Server Error'),
        (NotFound, '404 Not Found'),
    ),
    default = 'json',
    html = render_html_exception,
    xml  = render_xml_exception,
    json = render_json_exception,
    txt  = render_txt_exception
)
@mimerender(
    default = 'json',
    html = render_html,
    xml  = render_xml,
    json = render_json,
    txt  = render_txt
)
def test(...
```

When a request works i get this response:

```
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 29
< Vary: Accept
< Server: Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3rc2
< Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2012 19:27:30 GMT
< 
* Closing connection #0
{"message": "Success"}
```

When a request fails and an exception is triggered:

```
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 401 Not Found
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 25
< Vary: Accept 
< Server: Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3rc2
< Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2012 19:16:45 GMT
< 
* Closing connection #0
["Not found"]
```

My question: With the exception I want the same kind of output so like this:

```
{'message': 'Not found'}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly `exception.args` is a list, and it is being returned as such :-)  To change this, simply change the datastructure you are returning.

In other words, change:

```
render_json_exception = lambda exception: json.dumps(exception.args)
```

to:

```
render_json_exception = lambda exception: json.dumps({"message": exception.args})
```

Or, if you *must* return only one message on error:

```
render_json_exception = lambda exception: json.dumps({"message": " - ".join(exception.args)})
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot this was still open, I already figured out now, but I was wondering if I could manipulate the 'Exception' class? Anyhow thanks for your response :-)